# Spark distributed matrix multiply and pseudo-inverse calculating

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I am very new in Apache Spark Scala. Can you help me with some operations?

I have two distributed matrix H and Y in Spark Scala.

I want to compute the pseudo-inverse of H and then multiply H and Y.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have tried this https://btsxj.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/multiplication-of-matrices-on-spark-mllib/comment-page-1/#comment-34 and I got a result for multiplying but for inverse I haven't any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation for the inverse.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors,Vector,Matrix,SingularValueDecomposition,DenseMatrix,DenseVector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

def computeInverse(X: RowMatrix): DenseMatrix = {
  val nCoef = X.numCols.toInt
  val svd = X.computeSVD(nCoef, computeU = true)
  if (svd.s.size < nCoef) {
    sys.error(s"RowMatrix.computeInverse called on singular matrix.")
  }

  // Create the inv diagonal matrix from S 
  val invS = DenseMatrix.diag(new DenseVector(svd.s.toArray.map(x => math.pow(x,-1))))

  // U cannot be a RowMatrix
  val U = new DenseMatrix(svd.U.numRows().toInt,svd.U.numCols().toInt,svd.U.rows.collect.flatMap(x => x.toArray))

  // If you could make V distributed, then this may be better. However its alreadly local...so maybe this is fine.
  val V = svd.V
  // inv(X) = V*inv(S)*transpose(U)  --- the U is already transposed.
  (V.multiply(invS)).multiply(U)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the pseudo-inverse of non-square matrices you need to be able to calculate the transpose (easy) and the matrix inverse (others have supplied that functionality). There are two different calculations, depending on whether `M` has full column rank or full row rank.

Full column rank means that the columns of the matrix are linearly independent which requires that the the number of columns is less than or equal to the number of rows. (In pathological cases, an mxn matrix with m>=n might still not have full column rank, but we'll ignore that statistical impossibility. If it is a possibility in your case, the matrix inversion step below will fail.) For full column rank, the pseudo-inverse is

```
M^+ = (M^T M)^{-1} M^T
```

where `M^T` is the transpose of `M`. Matrix multiply `M^T` by `M`, then take the inverse, then matrix multiply by `M^T` again. (I'm assuming `M` has real number entries; if the entries are complex numbers, you also have to take complex conjugates.)

A quick check to make sure you have calculated the psuedo-inverse correctly is to check `M^+ M`. It should be the identity matrix (up to floating point error).

On the other hand, if `M` has full row rank, in other words `M` is mxn with m<=n, the pseudo-inverse is

```
M^+ = M^T (M M^T)^{-1}
```

To check whether you have the correct pseudo-inverse in this case, right multiply with the original matrix: `M M^+`. That should equal the identity matrix, up to floating point error.

Answer (score 0):

**Matrix multiplication** is the easier one: there are several `Matrix` implementations with a `multiply` method in packages `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg` and `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed`. Pick whatever fits your needs most.

I have not seen **(pseudo-)inverse** anywhere in the Spark API. But `RowMatrix` is able to compute the *singular value decomposition* which can be used to calculate the inverse of a matrix. Here is a very naive implementation, inspired by [How can we compute Pseudoinverse for any Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458404/how-can-we-compute-pseudoinverse-for-any-matrix) (warning: dimensions of the 2x2 matrix are hard-coded):

```scala
val m = new RowMatrix(sc.parallelize(Seq(Vectors.dense(4, 3), Vectors.dense(3, 2))))
val svd = m.computeSVD(2, true)
val v = svd.V
val sInvArray = svd.s.toArray.toList.map(x => 1.0 / x).toArray
val sInverse = new DenseMatrix(2, 2, Matrices.diag(Vectors.dense(sInvArray)).toArray)
val uArray = svd.U.rows.collect.toList.map(_.toArray.toList).flatten.toArray
val uTranspose = new DenseMatrix(2, 2, uArray) // already transposed because DenseMatrix is column-major
val inverse = v.multiply(sInverse).multiply(uTranspose)
  // -1.9999999999998297  2.999999999999767    
  // 2.9999999999997637   -3.9999999999996767
```

Unfortunately, a lot of conversion from Matrix to Array and so forth is necessary. If you need a fully distributed implementation, try using `DistributedMatrix` instead of `DenseMatrix`. If not, maybe using Breeze is preferable here.

Comment: Thank you very much. With matrix multiplication I got familiarized. It works. Your code help me find psevdo-inverse for square matrix. Can you suggest how this should work for nonsquare matrices?

Comment: I have another question about Indices of the maximum values along rows of matrix. Can I do this in Spark Scala?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar enough with the topic myself. I thought of my answer as a proof-of-concept what would set you in the right direction, but now I'd recommend using a specialized library like Breeze. - Your other question should be an extra post with more details.